# PHP submit based on hidden input (session variable)

Tags: php, html

I have a web application for posting events on a post it board style site. I want to have it that a user can click on the "My Events" option on the navigation bar and all the events that they have posted will appear in it.

To do this I put a hidden input field with the value being the UserID based on the session variable from when they log in. I made the "My Events" button in the navigation bar a submit button so that when the user presses this it works almost like a search where the SQL query looks for values in the "Events" table in the database where the UserID is the value in the hidden field i.e. the logged in user's ID.

The code for the hidden input field and submit button can be seen below.

```html
<ul>
    <form action ="myevents.php" method="POST">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="hidden" name="myevents" value ="<?php echo $charityid;?>" >
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit">My Events</button>  
    </form>
</ul>
```

The problem is that if I press the back button on the browser it will not go back to the "My Events" page properly because this page is completely dependent on the submit button (likewise if I go directly to the myevents.php page via the URL). Is there a way to fix this? Or a better way to code it so that when I navigate to this page the query will run?

Comment: why use a hidden form field (which makes you dependent on having the user submit the form over and over again) instead of directly using the session variable on each page load?

Comment: Why not use the UserID value from the session variable instead of putting it in a hidden input? Otherwise, (if you need the form for other reasons) when the form is submitted you could store the relevant data in a cookie and use that data when myevents.php is revisited.

Comment: What I am trying to learn really is how to execute the PHP when the "myevents" page loads using the session variable, I am learning PHP. Is there a function similar to the onload function in HTML

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after here. Everything in PHP executes before the visitor get the page delivered to them (simply put, let's not overcomplicate things right now). When you submit the form, myevents.php is called and the code there is executed. If myevents is a typical page, it will complete its execution and send the generated output (usually HTML) to the client (browser). It follows that every PHP execution is the direct response to an action taken by the visitor (for example the submission of a form or click on a link).

Comment: This means that you need to write your code as a response to the visitor's actions, sometimes based on information that they have provided to you (such as text inputs in a form). In this case, you mention having a logged in user who is assigned an ID. Google "PHP session" and you will find a lot of valuable information. The most important part, for you: A logged in user is assigned a $_SESSION array that is unique to them where you can store any information (that they cannot change) that relates to them. This array is available on any php page that is initiated with the session_start() call.

Comment: Okay I think I understand, I am currently taking Session variables from login such as userid, typeofloggedinuser etc but the way I am executing my PHP on the myevents.php page is by taking the hidden input the same way as a user searched input (mainly because this is what I have on the rest of my site), so the PHP executes and searches for entries in the DB where userid is like the input in the hidden field but from what you are saying (if I understand correctly), rather than posting the hidden value, I can just query using the Session variable directly?

Comment: Yes, if you have stored the user ID in the session array (in $_SESSION['UserID'], for example) then you are better off using that directly instead of using a hidden input field. The 2 major reasons for this is: 1. When the user goes to myevents.php by means other than the form (for example typing the URL in the address bar or by clicking 'back') then the session variable will still be there (assuming the user is logged in, which you should check for). 2. Any user can easily change the value of a hidden input. They can not change the variables in the session array.

Comment: Also, a quick Stack Overflow lesson. You get notifications automatically when someone comments on a question you have asked. Commenters only get notifications if you specifically mention them (by using @UserName). If you want to continue discussing with someone, do a mention. I only noticed your reply because I decided to revisit this question. If I didn't do that, I would never have seen it as I wasn't notified.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution regarding the hidden input field feels like a very dirty one. What would happen if someone would manipulate the UserID in the hidden field? One could query any UserID if you don't run any other checks.

I'd suggest to save the UserID in a session, remove it from the HTML and execute the query using the UserID from the session.

Comment: I have limited experience with PHP and what I've been doing so far is mainly using it based on user-input but how do I execute the PHP based on when the "my events" page loads?